# time complexity of making change with two loops - javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What is the time complexity of the following function that returns the number of ways that you can make change given a value and denominations of coins (ie nickel, dime, etc)?  My answer is that it is o(n) since the second loop essentially "caches" the value that you are looking at for clarity sake and you could write this function without it. however, when I see two for loops I always am inclined to think o(n^2).  isn't the variable j almost like a temp variable and runs independent of 'i'?

```
var makeChange = function (value, denoms) {
  var changeCounts = { 0: 1};

  for (var i = 0; i < denoms.length; i++) {
    for (var j = denoms[i]; j <= value; j++) {
      var remainder = j - denoms[i];
      if (changeCounts[j]) {
        changeCounts[j] += changeCounts[remainder];
      } else {
        changeCounts[j] = changeCounts[remainder];
      }
    }
  }

  return changeCounts[value];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets frame the problem statement as :

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.

For example, for N = 4 and S = {1,2,3}, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}. So output should be 4. For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}. So the output should be 5.

In your code, In the outer loop you are iterating over all the denominations    (0 < i <= m-1).
In inner loop you are iterating from S[i] to sum n. lets now consider worst case scenario. Assume you have S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and N = 1000.

In the first iteration of outer loop when i = 0, your inner loop will iterate from 1 to 1000.
when i = 1, your outer loop will iterate from 2 to 1000. Similarly for ith iteration of inner loop, your outer loop will iterate from i+1 to 1000.

So we iterated 1000 + 999 + 998 + 997 + 996 = 4990 times in this case which is almost equal to 5000, basically N x M.

While computing algorithmic complexity we always have to consider worst case scenario. So time complexity of your solution is O(mn) where n is the total change and m is the number of denominations available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out what exactly you are trying to do through this code but with with Big O notation you always consider the worst case scenario in which case both the loops get executed for maximum number of times thus o(n^2). If some thing is getting cached and you can skip the loop then why do you need that loop? But for the code you posted the time complexity is o(n^2).